# Converter from @PathVariable DomainObject to String? (using ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, converters, spring-hateoas

I'm trying to call Spring's `ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn()` with a non-String type, which always fails. And I don't know which kind of `Converter` to use and where to register it.

Here's my Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/companies")
class CompanyController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/{c}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    void getIt(@PathVariable Company c) {
        System.out.println(c);
        Link link = linkTo(methodOn(getClass()).getIt(c));
    }

}
```

The `System.out.println(c)` works well. My `Company` Domain object get's fetched from DB. (I'm using `DomainClassConverter`)

But the other way doesn't work: `ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type @PathVariable Company to type String`

Do I just need a `Converter<Company, String>`? And where should I register it? I tried something within the `addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry)` method of `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`, but it did just display the same error. But after all I'm not sure what exactly I tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a "solution". It requires a lot copy & paste from Spring's classes, but at least it works!

Basically I had to copy `org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.AnnotatedParametersParameterAccessor` and change two lines:

```
class AnnotatedParametersParameterAccessor {
    ...
    static class BoundMethodParameter {
        // OLD: (with this one you can't call addConverter())
        // private static final ConversionService CONVERSION_SERVICE = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
        // NEW:
        private static final FormattingConversionService CONVERSION_SERVICE = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();

        ...

        public BoundMethodParameter(MethodParameter parameter, Object value, AnnotationAttribute attribute) {
            ...
            // ADD:
            CONVERSION_SERVICE.addConverter(new MyNewConverter());
    }

    ...
}
```

This class get's used by `ControllerLinkBuilderFactory`. So I had to copy & paste that, too.

And this one get's used by `ControllerLinkBuilder`. Also copy & paste.

My `Converter` just does `myDomainObject.getId().toString()`:

```
public class MyNewConverter implements Converter<Company, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(Company source) {
        return source.getId().toString();
    }   
}
```

Now you can use the copy&pasted `ControllerLinkBuilder` inside the controller and it works as expected!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, it is a [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/118). If you don't want to do copy & paste on every controller you can try something like this in your `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`. It works for me.

```
@Override
public void addFormatters(final FormatterRegistry registry) {
    super.addFormatters(registry);

    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.AnnotatedParametersParameterAccessor$BoundMethodParameter");
        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("CONVERSION_SERVICE");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        DefaultFormattingConversionService service = (DefaultFormattingConversionService) field.get(null);
        for (Converter<?, ?> converter : beanFactory.getBeansOfType(Converter.class).values()) {
            service.addConverter(converter);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I developed a [framework](https://github.com/osvaldopina/linkbuilder) to render links in spring hateoas and it supports annotated parameters (`@PathVariable` and `@RequestParam`) and arbitrary parameters types.

In order to render these arbitrary types you have to create a spring bean that implements `com.github.osvaldopina.linkbuilder.argumentresolver.ArgumentResolver` interface.

The interface has 3 methods:

1. `public boolean resolveFor(MethodParameter methodParameter)`

Is used to determine if the `ArgumentResolver` can be used to deal with the `methodParameter`. For example:

```
public boolean resolveFor(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
    return UserDefinedType.class.isAssignableFrom(methodParameter.getParameterType());
}
```

Defines that this `ArgumentResover` will be used for `UserDefinedType`.

2. `public void augmentTemplate(UriTemplateAugmenter uriTemplateAugmenter, MethodParameter methodParameter)`

Is used to include in the uriTemplate associated with the method the proper template parts. For example:

```
@Override
public void augmentTemplate(UriTemplateAugmenter uriTemplateAugmenter, MethodParameter methodParameter) {
    uriTemplateAugmenter.addToQuery("value1");
    uriTemplateAugmenter.addToQuery("value2");

}
```

adds 2 query parameters (value1 and value2) to the uri template.

3. `public void setTemplateVariables(UriTemplate template, MethodParameter methodParameter, Object parameter, List<String> templatedParamNames)`

Sets in the template the values for the template variables. For example:

```
@Override
public void setTemplateVariables(UriTemplate template, MethodParameter methodParameter, Object parameter, List<String> templatedParamNames) {
    if (parameter != null && ((UserDefinedType) parameter).getValue1() != null) {
        template.set("value1", ((UserDefinedType) parameter).getValue1());
    }
    else {
        template.set("value1", "null-value");
    }

    if (parameter != null && ((UserDefinedType) parameter).getValue2() != null) {
        template.set("value2", ((UserDefinedType) parameter).getValue2());
    }
    else {
        template.set("value2", "null-value");
    }
}
```

gets the `UserDefinedType` instance and use it to sets the templates variables value1 and value2 defined in `augmentTemplate` method.

A `ArgumentResolver` complete example would be:

```
@Component
public class UserDefinedTypeArgumentResolver implements ArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean resolveFor(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        return UserDefinedType.class.isAssignableFrom(methodParameter.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public void augmentTemplate(UriTemplateAugmenter uriTemplateAugmenter, MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        uriTemplateAugmenter.addToQuery("value1");
        uriTemplateAugmenter.addToQuery("value2");

    }

    @Override
    public void setTemplateVariables(UriTemplate template, MethodParameter methodParameter, Object parameter, List<String> templatedParamNames) {
        if (parameter != null && ((UserDefinedType) parameter).getValue1() != null) {
            template.set("value1", ((UserDefinedType) parameter).getValue1());
        }
        else {
            template.set("value1", "null-value");
        }

        if (parameter != null && ((UserDefinedType) parameter).getValue2() != null) {
            template.set("value2", ((UserDefinedType) parameter).getValue2());
        }
        else {
            template.set("value2", "null-value");
        }
    }
}
```

and for the following link builder:

```
   linksBuilder.link()
            .withRel("user-type")
            .fromControllerCall(RootRestController.class)
            .queryParameterForUserDefinedType(new UserDefinedType("v1", "v2"));
```

to the following method:

```
@RequestMapping("/user-defined-type")
@EnableSelfFromCurrentCall
public void queryParameterForUserDefinedType(UserDefinedType userDefinedType) {

}
```

would generate the following link:

```
{
    ...
    "_links": {
        "user-type": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/user-defined-type?value1=v1&value2=v2"
    }
    ...
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

full config in spring boot. same as Franco Gotusso's answer just provide more detail.
```

/**
 * This configuration file is to fix bug of Spring Hateoas.
 * please check https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/118.
 */

@Component
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Override
public void addFormatters(final FormatterRegistry registry) {
    super.addFormatters(registry);

    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("org.springframework.hateoas.mvc."
                + "AnnotatedParametersParameterAccessor$BoundMethodParameter");
        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("CONVERSION_SERVICE");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        DefaultFormattingConversionService service =
                (DefaultFormattingConversionService) field.get(null);
        for (Formatter<?> formatter : applicationContext
                .getBeansOfType(Formatter.class).values()) {
            service.addFormatter(formatter);
        }
        for (Converter<?, ?> converter : applicationContext
                .getBeansOfType(Converter.class).values()) {
            service.addConverter(converter);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

}

```