# How to configure MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter registered by spring-hateoas

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

I like to use spring-hateoas in my project and configured it with `@EnableHypermediaSupport`.
The problem now is, that this magic config annotation registers its own `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and my own customized converter will be ignored.

Background: I added some Jackson modules (like the `JodaModule`) to my project and I want them to get registered using `objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();`. This is done by overriding `configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)` in `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` or `WebMvcConfigurer`.

My current configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HAL)
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

  @Override
  protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.getObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules();

    converters.add(converter);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to customize the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` or the `ObjectMapper` that is used by spring-hateoas?

Comment: What you means customize MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter ? Override its behaviour? If you want to override ObjectMapper, you can call MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper() and configure that ObjectMapper as you like.

Comment: I'm definitely interested in knowing how to do this as well. I think there are at least 3 (maybe 4 or more) different ObjectMapper instances initialized per Spring application context when you use Spring HATEOAS. I have not been able to configure any of them; the only way I can do it is through annotating the target classes, which is kind of a pain for global preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an ugly solution for my problem:

I'm using a BeanPostProcessor and a lot of reflection magic, to replace Spring HATEOAS' internal ConversionService with my own one, that has been added to the Spring context before. This way I make sure, that Spring HATEOAS uses exactly the same ConversionService as Spring MVC.

```
/**
 * This is a HACK to work around a not yet implemented feature. At the moment Spring Hateoas uses a
 * {@link ConversionService}, which is hold in a private static final field and hence cannot be accessed to add more
 * Converters<br/>
 *
 * <ul>
 *   <li><a href="https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/118">Spring Hateoas Issue</a></li>
 *   <li><a
 *     href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240155/converter-from-pathvariable-domainobject-to-string-using-controllerlinkbuilde">
 *     Solution on Stackoverflow</a></li>
 * </ul>
 */
public static class HateoasConversionServicePostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof ConversionService) {
            try {
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(
                        "org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.AnnotatedParametersParameterAccessor$BoundMethodParameter");
                Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("CONVERSION_SERVICE");
                field.setAccessible(true);

                Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
                modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
                modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

                field.set(null, bean);

                modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & Modifier.FINAL);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }

        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: The advantage of this solution compared to Chris' one is, that the complete ConversionService may contain more useful Converters than just the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter. HATEOAS uses its ConversionService not only for mapping the result to JSON, but also to convert objects used as parameters in the link builder API to URL path variables.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same thing.  With HATEOAS .16 i was able to ge this working..but really really ugly.

The key was that in the HypermediaSupportBeanDefinitionRegistrar the part that registers the HAL converter checks to see if there already is a HAL converter before it tries to add another one.  So I just added a HAL Converter in my WebMVCConfig::configureMessageConverters myself.

Something like:

```
private static final String DELEGATING_REL_PROVIDER_BEAN_NAME = "_relProvider";
private static final String LINK_DISCOVERER_REGISTRY_BEAN_NAME = "_linkDiscovererRegistry";
private static final String HAL_OBJECT_MAPPER_BEAN_NAME = "_halObjectMapper";

@Autowired
private ListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

private static CurieProvider getCurieProvider(BeanFactory factory) {

    try {
        return factory.getBean(CurieProvider.class);
    } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> baseConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        super.configureMessageConverters(baseConverters);

        //Need to override some behaviour in the HAL Serializer...so let's make our own
        CurieProvider curieProvider = getCurieProvider(beanFactory);
        RelProvider relProvider = beanFactory.getBean(DELEGATING_REL_PROVIDER_BEAN_NAME, RelProvider.class);
        ObjectMapper halObjectMapper = beanFactory.getBean(HAL_OBJECT_MAPPER_BEAN_NAME, ObjectMapper.class);

        halObjectMapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
        halObjectMapper.setHandlerInstantiator(new Jackson2HalModule.HalHandlerInstantiator(relProvider, curieProvider));

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter halConverter = new TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(
            ResourceSupport.class);
        halConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(HAL_JSON));
        halConverter.setObjectMapper(halObjectMapper);

        converters.add(halConverter);
    }
```

This is clearly implementation dependent, uses implementation details, and really doesn't let you modify the one that @EnableHyperMediaSupport build for you....but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following approach

```
@Configuration
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HypermediaType.HAL)
public class MvcConfig {    

  @Bean
  public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter() {
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at all... spring-hateoas 0.16.0.RELEASE still cannot convert my Resource/entities using the registered modules. :(